# User registration using UserCreationForm failing to save to database

Tags: django, sqlite, django-forms, django-views

I've been learning Django and I'm trying to understand how to extend some of the built-in functionality. To do that I've referenced [Customizing Authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) and tried to implement the instructions I've found there in a standard django-admin project.

The problem is that when I try to save the form to the database (sqlite3 included db), nothing is recorded. The form passes the is_valid check, but when I check the database however, nothing has been added to either my user or patients tables.

Hoping someone can point out where this is going wrong, thank you.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    isPatient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from .models import *

class RegisterPatient(UserCreationForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ("age")

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterPatient, self).save(commit=False)
        user.isPatient = True
        user.save()
        patient = Patient.objects.create(user=user)
        patient.firstName.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('age'))
        patient.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def register(response):
    form = RegisterPatient(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("is Valid") # < Code reaches here
        form.save
        return redirect("/")
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from . models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: @forpas When I submitted the first post, stackoverflow returned a message saying there was an error, so I tried again. I deleted the older post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `form.save` with `form.save()`. The latter calls the save function, whereas the former does not.